# Error when run project several times

Tags: java, android

I have a code that worked very good. But when i run several it, my app crashes for this error:

```
03-24 14:47:34.542    3489-3546/com.example.com E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

My code:

```
public class Sample {
public Sample(Context context) {//error for this line
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();}

 public void doSignUp( String firstName, String lastName, String userName) {
       //some code for signup users
}
}

public class Service {
   Runnable task  = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Sample sample = new Sample(getApplicationContext());
                Sample.doSignUp(firstName,lastName,userName);
                decreaseCounter();
                if(getCounter() <= 0){
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: I posted code please note that it does not work when several time run it and then when remove my project and recreate, workes

Comment: See  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can't manipulate UI directly from worker threads.

Comment: your class 'service' and 'sample' are plain java classes or they extend one of the android framework classes?

Comment: service extend service and sample does extend any thing

Comment: The error is because you are trying to access from a thread of a background class (service). Move it to a UI thread, simplest would be to call runOnUiThread()

Comment: @RusheelJain That's not true. Please refer to the docs for the [`Service` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html): "Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process."

Comment: My problem still there is and I realy need help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are probabley trying to update a UI componenet from a background thread (That is-a thread that does not run on the main thread - or "The UI thread" asyou will probabley read on other places), in order to achieve that you should pass a "Handler" that was created on either activity or a fragment (or something else that got created on the Main\UI thread) since the handler is connected to WHERE IT WAS CREATED it will act as a "bridge" between the two thread.
The error you are getting is from the OS, That Looper object is the one responsible to "push" tasks to the main\ui thread task queue.
You can also use asynctask that will essentially do the above for you.